# Dropdown list in grails

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu, html-table, gsp

In my program, which is a project tracker, I have a table with rows corresponding to the projects, and columns corresponding to the different information about the project (name, due date, status etc.). The last column should be 'More' column, that should display a dropdown list of additional attributes of the project whenever you press it. How do I do that in Grails? 
  Below is my list.gsp:

```
<calendar:resources lang="en"/>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="layoutMain"/>
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'project.label', default: 'Project')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><button>New Project</button></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="list-project" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'Name')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="dueDate" title="${message(code: 'project.dueDate.label', default: 'Due Date')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="startDate" title="${message(code: 'project.startDate.label', default: 'Start Date')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="status" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'Status')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="requirements" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'Requirements')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="design" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'Design')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="development" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'Development')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="qa" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'QA')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="ua" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'UA')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="delivery" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'Delivery')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="more" title="${message(code: 'project.name.label', default: 'More')}" />   

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${projectInstanceList}" status="i" var="projectInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:formatDate date="${projectInstance.dueDate}" /></td>

                        <td><g:formatDate date="${projectInstance.startDate}" /></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "status.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "requirements.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "design.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "development.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "qa.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "ua.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "delivery.name")}</g:link></td>

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${projectInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: projectInstance, field: "delivery.name")}</g:link></td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${projectInstanceTotal}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use standard Grails you can create a dropdown in Grails using a [g:select](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/select.html) tag. A prettier solution might be to use jQuery (or similar) to show hide a block of HTML.

If your project domain looks something like:

```
class Project {

    String name
...
    // more info
    String  attr1
    int     attr2
    boolean isAttr3

}
```

You can add a convenience method to your domain to aggregate the fields into a list (or possibly another object) that can be used for a drop down box. E.g.

```
// utility getter to aggregate the fields into an array 
def getMoreInfo() {
    [attr1, attr2, isAttr3]
}
```

Then you can use the following in your GSP:

```
<td><g:select name="more" from="${projectInstance.moreInfo}" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the click of more column you can send an Ajax request to some action which can bring you JSON of two arrays:

```
{extraColumns:{c1,c2}, columnValues:{{v11,v12}, {v21,v22}}}
```

In the response of Ajax you can parse the JSON and create additional columns for headers and additional column values for rows.